# What You Can’t Do with Generic Types

Tags: java, generics

I was going through the Java Generics and found the following limitation :-

1. Create an array of that static type. This one is the most annoying, but it makes sense
   because you’d be creating an array of Objects.
2. Call `instanceof`. This is not allowed because at runtime `List<Integer>` and
   `List<String>` look the same to Java thanks to type erasure.
   But the following code is compiled fine.

   ```
   interface Shippable<T> {
     void ship(T t);
   }
   class ShippableAbstractCrate<H> implements Shippable<H> {
     public void ship(H t) {
       if(t instanceof Object) {
         //do something 
       }
     }
   }
   ```

3.Create a static variable as a generic type parameter. This is not allowed because the
type is linked to the instance of the class.

Can you please provide the clarification with  examples.
I'm asking why all 3 points are limitation in generics ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Im asking for why all 3 points are limitation in generics ?

Comment: Really WHY? The answer would be, "because at run-time, the generic type information is erased". As ANY 3 second google search would tell you.

Comment: No i cant find my answer there

Answer (score 1):

2. means you can't write

   ```
   if(t instanceof H)
   ```

   You can always write `if(t instanceof Object)`
3. means you can't define the following static variable in your `ShippableAbstractCrate` class:

   ```
   static H someName;
   ```

Comment: isn't 2 meant to be (also?) something like `H instanceof String`?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The first operand of `instanceof` can't be a type anyway, so `H instanceof String` would fail for a different reason, not related to generics at all (just like  `Integer instanceof String`  would fail, unless you have some variable called `Integer` in scope).

Comment: but isn't that exactly was is meant, based on the mention that `List<String>` looks the same as `List<Integer>` at runtime? or should it be `t instanceof List<String>` that is not possible?